# Converting a decimal number to a number having all 1s in another base

Tags: number-theory, decimal-expansion

I am actually trying to solve the problem: "Beautiful Numbers", asked in Google Kickstart $2017$ Practice Round $2$ (Link: https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/12254486/dashboard#s=p2). The problem statement is:

> Given an integer $N$, can you find a base $B$ (with $B > 1$) to write it in
>   such that all of its digits become $1$? If there are multiple bases that
>   satisfy this property, choose the one that maximizes the number of $1$
>   digits.

I have been trying to get some "number theoretic idea" for sometime (given that I am not quite good at it). I know that for a number $N$, $N-1$ is a solution. But it need not be the *optimal* solution, as per the question. Is there a "clever" way to think about it?

(Some pointers in the right direction will help -- I can type down the solution on my own)

Comment: In base $b$, the number $11...11$ can be computed using the geometric series, since ($k$ times)$111..111 = b^{k-1} + b^{k-2} + ... + 1 =\frac{b^k - 1}{b-1}$. Therefore, it is enough to see if $N$ is of the form $\frac{b^k - 1}{b-1}$ for some $b$. I am sure it is enough to check for $b$ up to some easy-to-compute bound in $N$.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Thanks! But how to choose k efficiently?

Comment: We get $k \leq \log_2 N + 1$ , since the most number of digits $N$ can have in any base is the number of digits it has in base $2$.

Comment: $2^k-1 \leqslant N$ iff $k \leqslant \frac{\log (N+1)}{\log 2}$, so for larger $k$ you can't write $N$ using $k$ $1$'s.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Thanks! That was really great help! More, precisely, $k \leq \lfloor \log_{2}N \rfloor + 1$, right?

Comment: @TeddantheTerran Thanks! :) Please see the comment above!

Comment: @Python_user Yes, I  think that is true. Write $k$ in terms of $b$ and $n$ by using the formula I provided. Try to test values of $b$ using this.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Hey! Thanks! This helped me in solving the problem! :) . If you type down the comment as an answer, then I can mark it as the correct answer

Comment: Thank you, I shall do that now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In base $b$, the number $11...11$ can be computed using the geometric series, since ($k$ times)$111..111=b^{k−1}+b^{k−2}+...+1=\frac{b^{k−1}}{b−1}$. Therefore, it is enough to see if $N$ is of the form $b^k−1 \over b−1$ for some $b$. I am sure it is enough to check for $b$ up to some easy-to-compute bound in $N$. Certainly $k$ needs to be checked only up to $\log_2 N + 1$, since the maximum number of digits that $N$ has in any base is $\lfloor \log_2 N + 1 \rfloor$. Therefore, if we write $k$ in terms of $b$ and $r$, then we can see if any $1 \leq b \leq N$ works out. Certainly this is doable in short time.